# Sentence choice

Tags: tense

1. He is one of the greatest men who have ever lived.
2. He was one of the greatest men who ever lived.

Sentence 2 looks wrong to me because we cannot use *ever* with past tense in this case as people are still present on this world.

Comment: "who ever lived" is correct in AmE. In BrE, "who have ever lived" is the only possible form.

Comment: who ever lived is not just AmE.I do think he is the greatest novelist who ever lived. The Guardian https://www.theguardian.com/global/2010/jan/06/leo-tolstoy-greatest-writer

Comment: Both versions are definitely *syntactically* correct, and they both make *semantic* sense. . The only grounds to reject one or the other would be based on style or one or the other not being idiomatic. They are both idiomatic as far as *I'm* concerned. (But I'm Canadian, so I follow both US and UK English. But that's assuming regionalism is even a distinction here; I have my doubts about that.)

Comment: According to BBC (https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv123.shtml): Past-time adverbs, such as just, **ever**, already and yet are often used with the past simple in American English, whereas in British English they would normally be used with the present perfect.

Comment: This is confusing I mean which one should I use?